# What does this phrase in Yue Fei Temple mean? (Characters identified: 忠孝千秋)

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]

Most of the phrases put up in [Yue Fei Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yue_Fei_Temple) are easy to read, but this one is in Seal Script and I can't figure it out. I know the first character to be 忠, but the others I can't figure out. On the left I can see this was made in the winder of 2012, but I can't find out any information on google about this.

Comment: Seems like 忠義千秋 to me

Comment: @TangHo I think you're correct about [干](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%E5%8D%83), but for [義](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%E7%BE%A9) I get a way different Seal Script. Kknews does mention that phrase but in a different character order: [link](www.kknews.cc/zh-hk/travel/5j2ag9l.html)

Comment: Generally, you should treat seal script as a *font style*. This means you'll get more out of checking character components, rather than whole characters. The "seal script" listed at ctext is a particular dictionary standard prescribed by 說文解字. As with any dictionary standard in any language, their character structure (aka *spelling*) is *defined*, and may not reflect the character structure actually in use. 秋 is a prime example, in 說文 it is "spelt" as 秌, so you would have done better by recognising 禾 and 火 separately rather than checking 說文 and seeing something reverse to what you're used to.

Comment: @dROOOze thanks so much. Yeah, that was my approach, but in this case I was baffled none the less, hahaha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 忠孝千秋 (Thanks to the [link](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%E5%AD%9D) Johan88 provided)

[image] = 忠

[image] = 孝

[image] = 千

[image] =  秋 (The image from the site used 秌, which is an older version of 秋. The people who made the plaque used the 秋 modern Chinese use )

Comment: Amazing ! You found it ! Thanks. But why are the two radicals in 秋 reversed ?

Comment: Maybe a mistake, maybe for an artistic reason. Very likely the site made a mistake

Comment: You’ve taken the characters from 說文小篆. In 說文解字, 秋 is written as 秌. There is no mistake, but your images don’t match the photo.

Comment: 秌 is [an old variant of 秋](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%A7%8C)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I was about to search variant of 秋

Comment: So, what does 忠孝千秋  means?

Comment: 忠 = loyal , 孝 = filial；千秋 = forever